# Error " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' " while trying to create a .txt file

Tags: c++

I want to create code that will write some information to a `.txt` file, which I will later need to import in a `.py` script, so I can make a graph using Matplotlib with information written in the `.txt` file.

But, whenever I run my code, it prints the same error, no matter what I do to fix it. I looked up for some solutions here on StackOverflow, but none of them helped. I'm a beginner, so I don't understand C++ very well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class HarmonicOscillator {
private:
    double x, v;
    double dt = 0.001;

    vector<double> X;
    vector<double> V;
    vector<double> A;
    vector<double> T;

    void move();

public:
    HarmonicOscillator(double x0, double v0, double K, double m, double time);

    double _x0, _v0;
    double _K, _m;
    double _time;

    double write_file();
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <HarmonicOscillator.h>

using namespace std;

void HarmonicOscillator::move() {
    A.push_back(-(_K / _m) * X.back());
    V.push_back(V.back() + A.back() * dt);
    X.push_back(X.back() + V.back() * dt);
}

double HarmonicOscillator::write_file() {
    for (int i; i < T.size(); i++) {
        move();
    }

    X.pop_back();
    V.pop_back();
    A.pop_back();
    ofstream ofs("oscillatort.txt", ofstream::out);

    if (ofs.is_open()) {
        for (auto &x : X) {
            for (auto &v : V) {
                for (auto &a : A) {
                    for (auto &t : T) {
                        ofs << x << "-o-" << v << "-o-" << a << "-o-" << t << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Error."<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

HarmonicOscillator::HarmonicOscillator(double x0, double v0, double K, double m, double time) {
    _x0 = x0;
    _v0 = v0;
    _K = K;
    _m = m;
    _time = time;
    A.push_back(-(_K / _m) * _x0);
    V.push_back(_v0);
    X.push_back(_x0);
    T.push_back(0.0);

    while (T[-1] <= _time) {
        T.push_back(T[-1] + dt);
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <HarmonicOscillator.h>

int main() {
    double time = 4.0;
    HarmonicOscillator oscilator(-10, 0, 2.5, 150, time);

    oscilator.write_file();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think ‘T[-1]’ does?

Comment: Are you saying `terminate()` the function was called, or are you saying that the application terminated? Those are distinct situations.

Comment: @MikeVine I believe " T[-1] " addresses the last element of an array. I use it here for the while loop to run as long the T array does not have an element that is numerically larger that variable " time ".

Comment: @MartinYork I don't have a function ```terminate()``` in my code.  It just throws error that is written in the title.

Comment: `I believe " T[-1] " addresses the last element of an array.` Not in C++.

Comment: `std::terminate()` is part of the implementation and called under specific situations (and cause the application to exit).

Comment: @MartinYork my bad... I've changed it for ```back()``` function, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: The exception `std::bad_alloc` is generated when the system can not allocate enough memory for something. This suggests that the vectors are growing to large. The example code you provide about does not grow the vectors very large so it looks like this is not the code that is having the issues.

Comment: PS. You should fix the warnings in this code.

Comment: You have 4000 datapoints, that is, 4000 elements in each of the vectors `X`, `V`, `A` and `T`. Then you are trying to write 4000^4 aka 256*10^12 aka 256 trillion lines to the file - not one per datapoint, but one per every possible combination of elements of the four vectors. I don't think that's what you wanted to do.